# iOS: PHP web service using SOAP returns null when called

Tags: php, ios, xml, web-services, soap

Created a web service with .php extension and I am passing parameters though soap. But what it returns is out of my understanding. I also check on RestClient with proper input then it returned with actual output. Which is not going on properly in code. What may gone wrong ?

my xml structure for input is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <soap:Header>
 </soap:Header>
 <soap:Body>
   <getUpdates>
  <user_location></user_location>
  <application_type>FC</application_type>
  <last_updated_date>2014-11-25</last_updated_date>
  <platform>Android</platform>
  </getUpdates>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

and my web service method is,

```
-(void) notifyDatacalled
{

    NSString * post= @"<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><soap:Header></soap:Header><soap:Body><getUpdates><user_location>new york</user_location><application_type>free</application_type><last_updated_date>2014-12-12</last_updated_date><platform>ios</platform></getUpdates></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";


    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://game.techone.com/webservices/service.php"];

    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setTimeOutSeconds:30];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setPostBody:[[post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] mutableCopy]];
    [request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"text/xml"];
    [request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Length" value:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[post length]]];
    [request addRequestHeader:@"SOAPAction" value:@"getUpdates"];
    [request setPostLength:[post length]];
    [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
    [request startSynchronous];

    NSError *error = [request error];
    if (error)
    {

    }
    else
    {
           NSString *XmlResult = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[request responseString]];
            NSDictionary *dictioneryResult = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:XmlResult error:nil];
  }
}
```

Response that I am getting is,

```
"SOAP-ENV:Envelope" =     {
        "SOAP-ENV:Body" =         {
            "ns1:getUpdatesResponse" =             {
                return =                 {
                    "SOAP-ENC:arrayType" = "xsd:anyType[0]";
                    "xsi:type" = "SOAP-ENC:Array";
                };
                "xmlns:ns1" = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
            };
        };
        "SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle" = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/";
        "xmlns:SOAP-ENC" = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/";
        "xmlns:SOAP-ENV" = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
        "xmlns:xsd" = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
        "xmlns:xsi" = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
    };
```

Comment: You are getting JSON back. This is fairly normal for a REST service. Sounds like your PHP service isn't returning XML.

Comment: ohh, I see. Let me check.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
[request addRequestHeader:@"Accept" value:@"text/xml"];
```

to your webservice request.  The REST service you are calling is defaulting to json.  Many often return XML upon request.